# Why do we need hashcode and bucket in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Lately,I've been going through implementations of `Map` interface in `java`. I understood `HashMap` and everything made sense.
But when it comes to `LinkedHashMap`, as per my knowledge so far, the Entry has `key`, `value`, `before` and `after`. where before and after keeps track of order of insertion.

However, using `hashcode` and bucket concept doesn't make sense to me in `LinkedHashMaps`.

[I went through this article for understanding implementation of linkedHashMaps](http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/02/linkedhashmap-custom-implementation.html)

Could someone please explain it? I mean why does it matter in which bucket we put the entry node. In fact why bucket concept in the first place.? why not plain doubly llinked lists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` is still a type of a `HashMap`. It uses the same logic as `HashMap` in order to find the bucket where a key belongs (used in methods such as `get()`,`put()`,`containsKey()`,etc...). The `hashCode()` is used to locate that bucket. This logic is essential for the expected `O(1)` performance of these operations.

The added functionality of `LinkedHashMap` (which uses the `before` and `after` references) is only used to iterate the entries according to insertion order, so it affects the iterators of the `Collection`s returned by the `keySet()`,`entrySet()` & `values()` methods. It doesn't affect where the entries are stored.

Without hashcodes and buckets, `LinkedHashMap` won't be able to lookup keys in the `Map` in `O(1)` expected time.

Comment: Do you mean everything in `LinkedHashMap` (like `get(),put(),contains()`) is same as `HashMap` ,except for traversal/iteration it uses before and after?

Comment: @ArunGowdru yes. Though methods such as `put()` and `remove()` also have some differences in LinkedHashMap - they contain additional logic to update the values of the `before` and `after` references.

Comment: @ArunGowdru In Java 8, `LinkedHashMap` doesn’t even override the `put` or `contains` methods but just uses the inherited methods. This works because `HashMap` has been designed to be extendable for `LinkedHashMap`, i.e. all nodes are created via [(package-private) overridable factory methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#1724) and it also invokes [dedicated callback methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#1764).